# verbose output for ip xfrm command?

Tags: centos, iptables, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have an up script for strongswan that adds policies like this: 
`ip xfrm policy add dir in src $PLUTO_PEER_CLIENT dst 0.0.0.0/0 proto any varl src $PLUTO_PEER dst $PLUTO_ME proto esp mode tunnel reqid $PLUTO_REQID level required priority 1500 mark 0xfffe`

I want to log the output of that command to a log file but there seems to be no output or verbose switch?

this gives me nothing:
`ip xfrm policy add dir in src $PLUTO_PEER_CLIENT dst 0.0.0.0/0 proto any varl src $PLUTO_PEER dst $PLUTO_ME proto esp mode tunnel reqid $PLUTO_REQID level required priority 1500 mark 0xfffe >> /var/log/mylog.log`

Comment: What output would you expect?

Comment: Output that includes the command that was run and if it succeeded or failed- like how verbose prettyuch always works

Answer (score 0):

iproute2 does not generate any output for modifying commands (like `add` or `del`) unless there is something wrong with the arguments or the kernel (e.g permission denied). In which case an error message is written to `stderr` (so to capture that you'd have to add `2>>&1` to your command, or directly redirect `stderr` to the log file without even changing `stdout`).

Whether the command was successful you can easily check via exit status (`$?` or via `|| <whatever should happen if the command fails>` after the command) as that's documented to be 0 on success and 1 or 2 on failure (refer to `man ip` for details).

And to log/see the command that was executed you could probably just rely on the shell (see e.g. [this question on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2853803/1158499)), or e.g. wrap the command so it's first echoed to the log and then executed.